# ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi, firmware, tpm

I'm experiencing system freezes and looking in the journal I see kernel (`4.14.15-1-MANJARO`) errors such as:

```
kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
```

(Yes the message is repeated, with exactly the same timestamp)

A bit later, I get:

```
tpm tpm0: A TPM error (379) occurred attempting get random
```

I'm running the latest version of firmware (v3.05) for my Asus UX330. My kernel is:

```
4.16.0-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 21 09:02:49 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any workaround besides praying for an updated UEFI / BIOS firmware from Asus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I emailed Asus support and they say that the laptop only supports Windows.

You could consider [disabling TPM if it is not being used](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=263918#p143116) - please comment if you work out how to do this.

Comment: My Asus Vivobook BIOS v313 does not seem to have this option, I disabled the secur boot option and is still showing this error

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Fedora 27 (4.14) on the same laptop, with the same BIOS, and experience the same error.  I switched 'Fast boot' to disable, in the BIOS, and I no longer get the error.

I'm not sure if this is just hiding it though so hopefully someone can answer that.

Comment: Fedora 27 4.16.6-300 x64 on ASUS Laptop, disabling FastBoot doesn't help :(

Comment: Disabling fast boot didn't help me either.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I could disable TPM from an option in the BIOS : under SECURITY, Disable "Trust Platform Technology" -> This disables the TPM chip.

Now my problem is gone...